# Multiple CIDR blocks per VPC

Tags: terraform, cidr, vpc

Here's my situation...
I'm trying to deploy an application to several customers.  Each customer will have their own VPC (for security and isolation purposes).  The IP addresses for the application cannot be changed.  I want to use VPC Peering in order to manage all customers.

So.. On one hand I need a subnet that's identical across all VPCs.  I also need a subnet in the VPC that's unique (otherwise peering falls apart).

In the AWS Console I'm able to build this scenario and it works.
Looking at a describe_vpc call there appears to be a `CidrBlockAssociationSet` which is a list of CIDR blocks.
Does Terraform support this?  Workarounds?

Thx

Comment: Something else I noticed... Even if there's just a single CIDR block defined, it's still represented as a CidrBlockAssociation with a single item.  Seems like Terraform should be able to handle this easily.

Comment: I dug up a bit of information.... Looks like this will be supported in a coming release: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/1568/commits

Comment: So you need to create Subnet in a VPC using Terraform?